# Error Message about the ANOVA analysis(Replication) in R

Tags: r

I am trying to do an ANOVA table of mean from mtcars data-set, but I am given this error message constantly----

```
## Warning in replications(paste("~", xx), data = mf): non-factors ignored: wt
```

Can someone help? I know I am not able to factor Weight in Mtcars dataset.

```
transform.mtcars<-transform(mtcars,cyl =factor(cyl),am =factor(am, label=c("Auto","Manual")), gear=factor(gear),cars=rownames(mtcars))
```

`model.tables(aov(mpg ~ wt,data = transform.mtcars),type ="means")`

```
## Warning in replications(paste("~", xx), data = mf): non-factors ignored: wt
```

Comment: the 'wt' variable in `mtcars` is a `numeric` type and thus will not respond to factor commands.

Comment: And do note that it was a _warning_ ; not an "error".